# Swagger Open Api expects a OneOfCatDog schema instead of Cat and Dog schemas

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I want to have two kinds of responses defined in my API: one for success when I return a domain object and one for the Error case.

Following the documentation here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/

I first tested out the example given in the documentation and added this to my `.yaml` file:

```
paths:
  /pets:
    patch:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Updated
components:
  schemas:
    Dog:
      type: object
      properties:
        bark:
          type: boolean
        breed:
          type: string
          enum: [Dingo, Husky, Retriever, Shepherd]
    Cat:
      type: object
      properties:
        hunts:
          type: boolean
        age:
          type: integer
```

When compiling I get the following error:
`cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   class OneOfCatDog`

Seems like it is expecting a schema in my components which is called `OneOfCatDog` which is exactly what I am trying not to have.

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Update:
Code is generated with

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static/MyApi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                                <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: how do you compile?

Comment: `mvn clean compile` or `mvn clean isntall`

Comment: _"When compiling ..."_ - What exactly are you compiling? The OpenAPI YAML file in your post is a text file, not compilable code. Did you use some code generator to generate code out of it? If yes, which codegen did you use and what is the language of the generated code?

Comment: @Helen`<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>`

Comment: Please post the plugin's config from your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @Helen it's in the post now

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10880